# Linq and join to different properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, reflection

I have a few entities which I would like to join by linq. The problem is that property on which I would like to join is dynamic. For example:

```
public class AClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AClassId{ get; set; }
    public virtual AClass A { get; set; }

    public string String_Value_1 { get; set; }
    public string String_Value_2 { get; set; }
    public string String_Value_3 { get; set; }
}

public class Mapping
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AClassId{ get; set; }
    public virtual AClass A { get; set; }

    public string ColumnDesc{ get; set; }
    public string ColumnMappingName { get; set; }
}
```

and for example in my table of AClass will be stored "n" - elements, each element can have different mapping of source where string data is stored.

`product_id = 1` will have mapping `{ColumnDesc = "x" and ColumnMappingName = 
    "String_Value_1"}`

// this means that value of property "x" is stored for this product in column String_Value_1

`product_id = 2` will have mapping `{ColumnDesc = "x" and ColumnMappingName = 
    "String_Value_2"}`

// this means that value of property "x" is stored for this product in column String_Value_2

`product_id = 3` will have mapping `{ColumnDesc = "x" and ColumnMappingName = 
    "String_Value_3"}`

// this means that value of property "x" is stored for this product in column String_Value_3

`product_id = 4` will have mapping `{ColumnDesc = "x" and ColumnMappingName = "String_Value_1"}`

// this means that value of property "x" is stored for this product in column String_Value_1

What I would like to do, is to get all values (from BClass) for AClass objects which have defined CoulmnDesc. I do not want to do it by 3 queries (string columns can be 10 or even more) but rather to do it dynamically by joining by property name or reflection with using lambda expresions

Comment: Are you structuring your data in this way because of a legacy system, or is this a new project? If it is new, I would structure the data totally different.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the proper solution for your problem, don't worry about the massive amounts of records, SQL Server will find a way to get your data really fast.

```
    public class AClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AClassId")]
        public virtual List<PropertyValue> PropertyValues { get; set; }
    }
    // Id = 1, Name = "P1"
    // Id = 2, Name = "P2"
    // Id = 3, Name = "P3"

    public class PropertyValue
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int AClassId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AClassId")]
        public virtual AClass A { get; set; }

        public int PropertyNameId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PropertyNameId")]
        public virtual PropertyName PropertyName { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
    // Id = 1, AClassId = 1, PropertyNameId = 1, Value = "p1 x1 y1"
    // Id = 2, AClassId = 1, PropertyNameId = 2, Value = "p1 x2 y2"
    // Id = 3, AClassId = 1, PropertyNameId = 3, Value = "p1 x3 y3"

    // Id = 4, AClassId = 2, PropertyNameId = 2, Value = "p2 x2 y2"
    // Id = 5, AClassId = 2, PropertyNameId = 3, Value = "p2 x3 y3"
    // Id = 6, AClassId = 2, PropertyNameId = 4, Value = "p2 x4 y4"

    // Id = 7, AClassId = 3, PropertyNameId = 3, Value = "p3 x3 y3"
    // Id = 8, AClassId = 3, PropertyNameId = 4, Value = "p3 x4 y4"
    // Id = 9, AClassId = 3, PropertyNameId = 5, Value = "p3 x5 y5"

    public class PropertyName
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PropertyId")]
        public virtual List<PropertyValue> PropertyValues { get; set; }
    }
    // Id = 1, PropertyName = "x1"
    // Id = 2, PropertyName = "x2"
    // Id = 3, PropertyName = "x3"
    // Id = 4, PropertyName = "x4"
    // Id = 5, PropertyName = "x5"

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        List<AClass> productlist = new List<AClass>();

        foreach (var product in productlist)
        {
            var productname = product.Name;

            foreach (var property in product.PropertyValues)
            {
                var propertyname = property.PropertyName.Name;
                var propertyvalue = property.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

[EDIT]

Your original solution is possible, I will show you for "learning purposes".

```
    public class AClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AClassId")]
        public virtual List<PropertySet> PropertySets { get; set; }
    }

    public class PropertySet
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int AClassId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AClassId")]
        public virtual AClass A { get; set; }

        public int PropertyNameId_Column1 { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PropertyNameId_Column1")]
        public virtual PropertyName PropertyName_Column1 { get; set; }
        public string Value_Column1 { get; set; }

        public int PropertyNameId_Column2 { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PropertyNameId_Column2")]
        public virtual PropertyName PropertyName_Column2 { get; set; }
        public string Value_Column2 { get; set; }

        public int PropertyNameId_Column3 { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("PropertyNameId_Column3")]
        public virtual PropertyName PropertyName_Column3 { get; set; }
        public string Value_Column3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class PropertyName
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PropertyNameId_Column1")]
        public virtual List<PropertySet> PropertySets_Column1 { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PropertyNameId_Column2")]
        public virtual List<PropertySet> PropertySets_Column2 { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PropertyNameId_Column3")]
        public virtual List<PropertySet> PropertySets_Column3 { get; set; }
    }
```

I added this solution so you can see how you can do multi mapping in EF. (think: AddedByUser, UpdatedByUser ect.) Please don't use this method to solve your problem, it will be a bad practice and a lot of work.

[/EDIT]

[EDIT2]

In the company where I used to work, I had this collega who said exactly the same thing ("this system will not work with millions of records"). He worked out some kind of bit-wise compare method to map his predefined properties. This system was indeed using 1.000.000+ records but I never took the time to properly disprove his method.

You are going to be my victim now ;) haha

I'm currently creating a test envirement with 5.000.000 products. Each product has 3 values assigned to it, creating a values table of 15.000.000 records.

[image]

[/EDIT2]

[EDIT3]

Ok, that was unexpected, I've done 2 tests:

Query 1. Select random 1.000.000 product

```
SELECT TOP 1000000 *
  FROM [test].[dbo].[products]
  ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Query 2. Select random 1.000.000 product, inner-join properties

```
SELECT TOP 1000000 *
  FROM [test].[dbo].[products] p
  INNER JOIN [test].[dbo].[View_1] v
  ON v.ProductId = p.Id
  ORDER BY NEWID()
```

And guess the results:

**Query 1: 3 a 4 seconds execute**

**Query 2: 7 a 8 seconds execute**

The results are exactly the same when enable foreign keys and primary key as without. I expect SQL server being perfectly able to handle 10.000.000 in memory, the database is only 2 gig is size.

Because of the "perfect" way of storing the information the database can query really easy using all kinds of optimalisations under the hood (because of the INNER JOINS). If I would select just 1 product, the results are there so fast, the timer stays at 0:00.

[/EDIT3]

Comment: Its new project. I see what you mean but if there will be 1 milion of AClass objects and each will have 5 string properites, in my table will be 5 milions of strings in the table. This is not what I want to have.

Comment: This will be handled though the foreign keys, they will act as indexes so searches will be needed only in memory, which is superfast. Anyways, I will make a new one. One moment please...

Comment: Added another way to adress this problem.

Comment: I this case how you want to get values of property name "X" which can be stored In one AClass Object in Value_Column_1 in next in Value_Column_2 and the other Value_Column_3 and in the other will not exists but will be other. I do not want to have 3 queries. My target is something similar to EAV pattern but I have read about it that in MS SQL is hard to implement it, is hard to make search, order etc. and handle it in Linq and EF, next idea was to do it by xml column, But EF doesn't support it :(. And next idea was to have "n - amount" string columns "y - amount" int columns etc with bool

Comment: You have 1 query: SELECT * FROM PropertyValue pv INNER JOIN AClass  a ON a.Id = pv.AClassId INNER JOIN PropertyName n ON n.Id = pv.PropertyNameId

Comment: But now your sql is from your first sugestion of data model. Which I dont want to have because of huge amount of rows in the table